# How do I get the parent li everytime I click one of the child li in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a list in WordPress that has the structure below

```
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

    <li class="woof_term_224  woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 1</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
            <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
                <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 1</label>

                <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_444">
                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 1</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 2</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_225  woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 2</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
            <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
                <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 2</label>

                <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_555">
                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 3</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 4</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Parent 1

        
            
                Sub Category 1

Product 1

Product 2

Parent 2

        
            
                Sub Category 2

Product 3

Product 4

I would like to find out the parent `<li>` if I click any of its children.

For example if I click Parent 1 OR Sub Category 1 OR Product 1 OR >Product 2, I woud like to find the parent  `<li class="woof_term_224  woof_childs_list_li">`

The same should be true for `<li class="woof_term_225  woof_childs_list_li">`

My current code looks like this but it's not working:

```
  j('.woof_list_radio > li > .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    j(this).closest('ul').closest('li').addClass('current')

  });
```

Any idea is appreciaed.

Comment: `e.target.parentNode.parentNode`??

Comment: How about: `$(this).parents('li.woof_childs_list_li').addClass('.current')`

Comment: just remove `.closest('ul')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcard jquery selector to travel up the DOM to find the first `li` begins with `woof_term_`:

```js
$('.woof_list_radio .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("li[class^='woof_term_']").addClass('current')
});
```

```css
.current{
  background-color: lightblue;
}
label{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

    <li class="woof_term_224  woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 1</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
            <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
                <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 1</label>

                <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_444">
                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 1</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 2</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>

    <li class="woof_term_225  woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 2</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
            <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
                <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 2</label>

                <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_555">
                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 3</label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 4</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @ConanCarroll Glad to help you.

Comment: Shouldn't you toggle all the currents out, so that you only have one current at a time?

Comment: @Stender Apparently is enought for what he needs. In that case he also can use `removeClass()` or `toggleClass()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: You just need to add class selector in `closest` for parent li and it will pick the correct li parent.
Also, add click event handler for all `woof_radio_label` inside `woof_childs_list_li`

```
 j('.woof_childs_list_li .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    j(this).closest('ul').closest('li.woof_childs_list_li').addClass('current')
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like: `$(this).closest('li[class^=woof_term_]').addClass('current');`

`li[class^=woof_term_]` will look for an `li` that has the class starting with `woof_term_`

**Demo**

```js
$('.woof_list_radio li .woof_radio_label').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('li[class^=woof_term_]').addClass('current');

});
```

```css
.current{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_radio">

  <li class="woof_term_224  woof_childs_list_li">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 1</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_224">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 1</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_444">
          <li>
            <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 1</label>
          </li>

          <li>
            <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 2</label>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

  <li class="woof_term_225  woof_childs_list_li">
    <label class="woof_radio_label " for="woof_unselect">Parent 2</label>

    <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_225">
      <li class="woof_childs_list_li">
        <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Sub Category 2</label>

        <ul class="woof_childs_list woof_childs_list_555">
          <li>
            <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 3</label>
          </li>

          <li>
            <label class="woof_radio_label" for="woof_unselect">Product 4</label>
          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```